# On Prem Large Table Move to Redshift AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection-timeout, aws-glue

I have the script below to move all columns in tables of varying sizes, 90 million to 250 million records deep from an on premises Oracle database to AWS Redshift. The script also appends several audit columns given:

```
add_metadata1 = custom_spark_df.withColumn('line_number', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))))
add_metadata2 = add_metadata1.withColumn('source_system', lit(source_system))
add_metadata3 = add_metadata2.withColumn('input_filename', lit(input_filename))
add_metadata4 = add_metadata3.withColumn('received_timestamp', lit(received_timestamp))
add_metadata5 = add_metadata4.withColumn('received_timestamp_unix', lit(received_timestamp_unix))
add_metadata6 = add_metadata5.withColumn('eff_data_date', lit(eff_data_date))
```

At present, the long running nature of the job causes a connection timeout after 3-5 hours and therefore has never finished:

```
  import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## Start - Custom block of imports ##
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import datetime 
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
## End - Custom block of imports ##

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "metadatastore", table_name = "TableName", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("...MAPPINGS OUTLINED...")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")

dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")

## Start - Custom block for creation of metadata columns ##
now = datetime.datetime.now()

##line_number = '1'
## Remember to update source_system (if needed) and input_filename
source_system = 'EDW'
input_filename = 'TableName' 
received_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

received_timestamp_unix = int((now - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())

eff_data_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d").date()

## Update to the last dataframe used
## Do not forget to update write_dynamic_frame to use custom_dynamic_frame for the frame name and add schema to the dbtable name
custom_spark_df = dropnullfields3.toDF()

add_metadata1 = custom_spark_df.withColumn('line_number', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))))
add_metadata2 = add_metadata1.withColumn('source_system', lit(source_system))
add_metadata3 = add_metadata2.withColumn('input_filename', lit(input_filename))
add_metadata4 = add_metadata3.withColumn('received_timestamp', lit(received_timestamp))
add_metadata5 = add_metadata4.withColumn('received_timestamp_unix', lit(received_timestamp_unix))
add_metadata6 = add_metadata5.withColumn('eff_data_date', lit(eff_data_date))

custom_dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(add_metadata6, glueContext, "add_metadata6")
## End - Custom block for creation of metadata columns ##

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = custom_dynamic_frame, catalog_connection = "Redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": "schema_name.TableName", "database": "dev"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

How can this script be improved to reduce run time and permit complete execution?

Comment: To understand what is slow separate the on-prem read from the redshift write.  Also, if you extract a file from Oracle to S3 you could use the redshift bulk loader to speed up the redshift load.

Comment: Is there sample code to use AWS Glue to load directly into S3 from a source?

Comment: Why do you want to go through Glue Job only. For me your case looks like database migration from on-prem oracle database into AWS Redshift.
if that is the case: "True"
I would go for AWS DMS service.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Sauron. I think you are better of creating CSV dump, gzip it, put it into s3. You can also convert it into parquet format using glue once the file is in S3. For one off  dump, this approach will be faster.

For your question on AWS Glue code to load into S3 from source, you just need to change the 2nd last line of your code which does the writing. Use something like below:

```
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = custom_dynamic_frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_output}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```